# PBEwithMD5andDES in C#

Tags: c#, java, md5, des

How should I specify a text input and output using this code?
I need to open a file and read its contents (which I know how to do) and then decrypt it using this code.

```
    public string DecryptUsernamePassword(string cipherText)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
        {
            return cipherText;
        }

        byte[] salt = new byte[]
        {
            (byte)0xc7,
            (byte)0x73,
            (byte)0x21,
            (byte)0x8c,
            (byte)0x7e,
            (byte)0xc8,
            (byte)0xee,
            (byte)0x99
        };

        PKCSKeyGenerator crypto = new PKCSKeyGenerator("PASSWORD HERE", salt, 20, 1);

        ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = crypto.Decryptor;
        byte[] cipherBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        byte[] clearBytes = cryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(clearBytes);
    }
```

cipherText is the encrypted text and clearBytes are the unencrypted bytes but I need to use a textBox with C# forms for input and output.

This is how it needs to work: textBox1.Text (input) -> bytes -> ^above^ string -> bytes -> textBox2.Text (output) Anything works tbh as long as my input is encrypted text and my output is decrypted text.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Does this code not work? Are you asking how to add this to some GUI with text boxes?

Comment: Exactly I should have added that instead of getting to the point of confusion of how I would explain my goal.

Comment: The best is to just find a C# winforms or WPF tutorial and adapt it to your needs. Just build your form with 2 text boxes. In a button click handler, you'd do something like: string result = DecryptUsernamePassword(inputTextBox.Text);

resultTextBox.Text = result;

Comment: I know how to do the forms easily that's not the problem this code happens to be a public string and I need it to be attached to a button handler.

Comment: Where is `PKCSKeyGenerator` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, assuming I'm still understanding the question properly. Make this into it's own class:

```
 public class UsernameDecryptor
 {
      public string Decrypt(string cipherText)
      {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
                return cipherText;


           byte[] salt = new byte[]
           {
                (byte)0xc7,
                (byte)0x73,
                 (byte)0x21,
                (byte)0x8c,
                (byte)0x7e,
                (byte)0xc8,
                (byte)0xee,
                (byte)0x99
            };

            PKCSKeyGenerator crypto = new PKCSKeyGenerator("PASSWORD HERE", salt, 20, 1);

            ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = crypto.Decryptor;
            byte[] cipherBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            byte[] clearBytes = cryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(clearBytes);
      }
 }
```

Then, inside your button handler:

```
private void button1_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     UsernameDecryptor decryptor = new UsernameDecryptor();

     string result = decryptor.Decrypt(inputTextBox.Text);

     outputTextBox.Text = result;
}
```

Comment: Keeps saying invalid length for a 64bit char array when I press the button.